# Customizing a jdbcChannelMessageStore in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I'm relatively new with SI (I say "relatively" because I did some work with SI version 0.6 to 1, but I had to stop then and I'm now on it again in 4.2.5) and for now I'm writing some prototypes for POCs. In one of then I configured a channel backed by a jdbcChannelMessageStore which I wanted to customize in a simple way. To change the column MESSAGE_BYTES from bytea to text.

So I changed the schema-postgresql.sql to include that change and hope that I could only rewrite the jdbc statement for the INSERT. However, even if the statement itself is easily changeable, setting the parameters is not, since it is buried inside a lambda inside the jdbcTemplate.update itself inside the addMessageToGroup method. So the only solution would be to override the entire addMessageToGroup method, which seems not a good solution at all, since it contains more logic than the simple jdbc insert.

So what ended up doing was what I commented on my code as // very big hack. I overriden the DefaultLobHandler to actually **not** use the lob at all but a setString(...) instead.

So, I have a question and a suggestion:

Is there a way customize the JdbcChannelMessageStore to have our own schema structure and/or our own statements, without using things like this "big hack"?

If there is no better way, can I suggest to at least put the prepared statement fields setters on it's own protected (or public) method, instead of a lambda inside the jdbcUpdate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should probably make it easier to override that logic, perhaps by delegating to an overridable method.

[Contributions are always welcome :)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.adoc).

Comment: I wish I have the time to do that, actually is not a big change, I think it will take more time to read the Contributor Guidelines than to write the code... :)

Comment: No problem - I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4081) if you want to track it.